# Is "complete list" idiomatic?

Tags: idiomatic-language

My another [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344427/714660) uses the expression "complete list".

[A meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/714660) uses "full list". So, I guess "full list" is idiomatic.

The question is,

Is "complete list" also idiomatic?

Are those 2 interchangeable in this context?

Comment: A list of what exactly??

Comment: @Lambie A list of privileges on SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, "complete list" is idiomatic. You can check several examples in [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/example/english/complete-list):

> A complete list is given in the related work section.
>
> I have no idea how many words a complete list would contain.
>
> etc.

There may be different contexts in which either a "complete" or "full" list is used more commonly. For example, in medical texts, they much more commonly use "a complete list of symptoms" than "a full list of symptoms."

Comment: Exactly, because there isn't such a thing as a full list of symptoms since we can't know them all, they keep versions and have a complete list to the current day.

Comment: @SovereignSun Thanks guys, Jan and SovereignSun. I feel that "complete list" might be more idiomatic than "full list", as Cambridge Dictionary does not even have a definition about "full list".

Answer (score 0):

In other contexts, "full" and "complete" mean different things. "Full" is normally used when speaking about something with a predefined *capacity*, for example, a jug could be full of liquid, but it does not contain all the liquid in the world.

A "list" does not have a defined capacity - it is either complete, or not. So, in the context of a list, "full" and "complete" are really synonymous. They can only mean the same thing. If a list were to become out of date, it would cease to be a full list, or a complete list.

Comment: A full list is a list that covers all the range of elements within a context, but it is always editable. A complete list is duplicate of a full list but with an agreement that at the moment of birth this list is the full range of all known elements.

Comment: See also Ngram:  ["a full list" vs "a complete list"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+full+list%2Ca+complete+list&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20full%20list%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20complete%20list%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score -1):

In terms of the subtle difference between "**full**" and "**complete**":

- a full list - is a list of all that wasn't omitted (also suggests that there exists or could exist a shortened list). It may be a list where certain elements may yet be removed, changed or added or it could be a general list of all certain elements in existence.
- a complete list - is a version of a full list that is committed, for instance as a result of an agreement, decision or resolution. Elements on this list are fixed as the total amount to the day of birth.

For instance we have a full list of participating condidates for a competition that hasn't yet started, we can cut that down to a complete list of competitors that eventually took part in the competition. As a result we get two lists, a full list of candidates who were initially registered for the competition and a complete list of competitors who did actually participate in the competition.

However, this difference is non-obligatory and ignored in many cases, except in business, IT and some others.

Comment: For the purposes of a list, "complete" and "full" can only mean the same thing - 100%. Any list can become out of date, and then it is neither full nor complete.

Comment: @FrankTownend You definitely don't work with IT documents and business papers. Especially with versions of documents.

Comment: Actually, yes I do - I'm an IT manager working in an ITIL environment, but I don't see how that has anything to do with the OP's question?

Comment: @SovereignSun Industries have their own terminology - the IT industry certainly does. For example, the dictionary definition of the word "unresolved" has no bearing on how it is used in the IT service industry. I think you are confusing your industry's use of words with English grammar.

Comment: @FrankTownend Well I am a programmer in IT and we have full lists, complete lists and signed lists, even incomplete full lists and full lists that are cut down to queried needs.

Comment: @Astralbee No, this is exactly about English grammar.

Comment: @SovereignSun Well, the scores are on the doors now.

Comment: @Astralbee I vote for Jan's answer

Comment: initial and final list of candidates.....

Comment: @Lambie And you really think that is idiomatic?

Comment: @SovereignSun Of course, it is and I really don't want to insult you but your answer has a number of issues.

Comment: @Lambie As a matter of fact everyone here insults me, I know for sure that I am absolutely right about my definition whereas you guys think I am wrong.