# "The question is that" vs. "The question is"

Tags: word-usage

In my other post ([Is "complete list" idiomatic?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/239363/109190)), I said

> **The question is**, is "complete list" also idiomatic?

In another post (["to write things with" vs. "to write things"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/239972/109190)), I said

> **The question is that**, is it more idiomatic or natural when using the preposition with?

I've also found [lots of people use these expressions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22The%20question%20is%20that%22).

I guess both are "**that**" clause, the former omits the word "that".

Are both grammatical and idiomatic?

How about [this one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/240039/109190)?

> I am aware of the usage of ... **The question is** the tense.

I guess the 3rd way I propose the question would be probably grammatical and idiomatic.

Comment: I don't like ***that*** in your context. Better would be *The question is **whether XXX is** also idiomatic?* (where we ***don't*** "invert" subject+verb XXX+is).

Comment: or '*The question is **this;** is it more ...*'