# Is it idiomatic to say "I didn't ... I do"?

Tags: word-usage

In one of my posts ([Is it grammatical and idiomatic to say "would be highly probably"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/240112/109190)) I said

> Before @Astralbee @KateBunting and @WeatherVane mentioned the other possibilities, I **didn't** consider highly probable, highly likely, almost certainly.

I was considering to add more,

> ... I **didn't** consider ..., **I do** now.

to indicate I learned something, I got some helpful information from those guys.

Is it idiomatic to say "I didn't ... I do"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite close there, but (no pun intended) what you are missing is the word "but".

I would suggest something along the lines of:
`I didn't consider <thing> until now, but now I do.`  or quite similar: `I hadn't thought about <thing> before, but now I have.`